# Deleting data from SQLite3 iPhone SDK?

Tags: sql, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, sqlite

Hey, 
How can I delete data from SQLite3 iPhone SDK? I am able to insert data into the database by using this code:

```
-(void)insertRecordIntoTableNamed:(NSString *)tableName
                   withField1:(NSString *)field1
                  field1Value:(NSString*)field1Value
                    andField2:(NSString *)field2
                  field2Value:(NSString *)field2Value
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '%@' ('%@' , '%@')     VALUES ('%@','%@')",tableName,field1,field2, field1Value,field2Value];
    char *err;      
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0,@"error updating table.");
    }
}
```

I think I have to change something in `NSString *sql` but I can't figure out what do I have to change it to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an SQL [`DELETE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) statement:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM '%@' WHERE '%@' = '%@'", tableName, field1, field1Value];
```

The `WHERE` clause, of course, depends on what you want to delete from `tableName`.